# mySQL - If statement giving syntax error

Tags: mysql

So I have the following query:

```
IF ( ( SELECT RevisionNumber FROM SchemaVersion ) > 1 ) THEN BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Test ( ID INT );
    CREATE TABLE Test2 ( ID INT );
END;
END IF
```

Basically I want to decide based on a value in my table (SchemaVersion - always has 1 row) whether or not I need to make certain changes.

However, when I use this query I get the following error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ( ( SELECT RevisionNumber FROM SchemaVersion ) > 1 ) THEN BEGIN
 CREATE T' at line 1
```

Any idea why this is erroring / how to fix?

I was just reading another post and apparently `BEGIN` / `END` are only allowed within stored procs.  Is there any way to get around this (without putting it in a stored proc).

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `IF` statement is part of what's called Compound-statement Syntax, and it is only available inside stored code, like a trigger, function, or stored procedure.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html

Comment: Thanks!  Not the answer I wanted (for obvious reasons) but points out the issue.

Comment: @judda: Since it looks like you are trying to do conditional schema updates, I'll offer a suggestion: You could write an update script that creates a stored procedure, calls it, and then drops it. Inside the procedure, you can use `IF ... THEN` only apply schema changes that aren't already applied.

Comment: This script is being generated through a bunch of flat files (i.e. ALTER statements) and then just being echoed together.  Right now they are all being combined into one big SQL file which is then used.  I guess I could have something that prefixes it with the create procedure and everything calls and then just give a link for that instead of the flat file it is based off of.  Great idea :)

Answer (score 4):

Using IF with brackets calls the `IF function`, which is different from `IF statement`

> Note There is also an IF() function, which differs from the IF
>   statement described here. See Section 11.4, “Control Flow Functions”.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to run that within a stored procedure. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html